# Frame functions are not working on Frame objects I created

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

My problem is that I can't get tkraise() to work on any of my frame objects. It does work when I use variables for storing the frames, but not when using objects. How to get tkraise() to work on my frame objects and have the blue_frame displayed? (all other frame functions also do not work)

For your info: I have a base frame (box), where all the other frames go in. Those frames are objects that I created using the New_Frame class, which inherits everything from the Frame class - which means I should be able to perform all kinds of Frame operations on my New_Frame class objects, but they're are not working e.g tkraise().

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.minsize(width=300, height=230)

box = Frame(root)
box.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
box.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
box.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

class New_frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self,color):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.color = color

        fr = Frame(box, bg=self.color)
        fr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# frame objects
blue_frame = New_frame("blue")
red_frame = New_frame("red")
green_frame = New_frame("green")

blue_frame.tkraise()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you a intending to create a total of seven frames (each `New_frame` has a frame inside it)? When you call `tkraise`, which frame do you intend for it to raise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are creating a frame seems highly unusual. You are creating two frames, with an inner frame that does not have the outer frame as a parent.

My guess is that you are intending for `New_frame` to be a single frame. If that's the case you need to remove the call to `Frame` from within the `__init__` of `New_frame`. Also, you should explicitly pass in the parent when creating an instance of `New_frame`.

For example:

```
class New_frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent, color):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=color)
        self.color = color
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# frame objects
blue_frame = New_frame(box, "blue")
red_frame = New_frame(box, "red")
green_frame = New_frame(box, "green")
```